# How can I see the button clicks, etc. on a website, so I can call it programmatically in the webbrowser-control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Let's say I go to a random site and click on a button. For example the search button on google.com happens to be named btnK and I can reproduce that click in C# webbrowser control by doing the following:

```
HtmlElementCollection elc = this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");

foreach (HtmlElement el in elc)
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit") && el.GetAttribute("name") == "btnK") 
        el.InvokeMember("click");
}
```

But how do I easily "debug" a website and see what actions are performed so I know what button is clicked?

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? There are already tools to facilitate the automatic black-box testing of websites e.g. Selenium

Comment: But, when you call your Click button, this call a function define in your xaml...
Why don't call this function from the beginning?

Comment: I don't know anything about webprogramming, so it might be the wrong approach. Basically, I want to be able to navigate websites programmatically. That's why I want to find a way to easily see the the names of the buttons I press , the text fields I type in, etc, so I can reproduce the same thing programmatically.

Comment: Try selenium http://seleniumhq.org/, it can do that. You basically 'record' a path through the website by clicking on buttons, links etc. and then it can be played back simulating what you just recorded. You can have multiple recordings to test multiple areas of functionality.